# Prononciation des genres des nuages: stratus, cirrus, cumulus

Tags: prononciation, ipa

Comment prononce-t-on les noms de genres des [nuages](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuage): *stratus*, *cirrus* et *cumulus*, ainsi que *cumulonimbus* ? J'apprecierais la transcription IPA. Une question liée: s'agit-il des termes techniques ou est-ce que ces sont des termes qu'on apprend à l'école ?

Comment: Toutes ces transcriptions IPA et les définitions sont disponibles dans le dico, https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/stratus ci-inclus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La prononciation des ces noms de nuages est n'a rien de particulier en dehors du fait que leurs *S* finals ne sont pas muets.

/stratys/, /siʁys/, /kymylys/, /kymylonɛ̃bys/.

Il s'agit de termes techniques mais ils peuvent être abordés au collège ou au lycée (en France).